# NHL standings in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have an SQL query that produces team standings based off the old NHL format.
 The first section of the code gets the top 3 teams in each division, and the 2nd bit gets the rest and sorts them by points/differential.

This can be seen here: http://rgmgstandings.tk

Here is my SQL query:

```
("(SELECT *, 1 as `SortKey` from `standings_east` 
        WHERE pts = (select max(pts) 
            from standings_east as t 
    where t.`div` = standings_east.`div`))

UNION ALL 

(select *, 2 as SortKey from `standings_east` 
        where team not in 
            (select team from standings_east 
                where pts = (select max(pts) 
                    from standings_east as t 
                        where t.`div` = standings_east.`div`))) 
        order by SortKey, pts desc, diff desc")
```

If you visit my website, and look at the standings for the Western Conference (blue banner), you will notice 3 teams in 'CEN' that have the same amount of points (Chicago, Winnipeg, Columbus)

[image: standings]

I want the query to select only ONE team from that division based on whoever has the most 'Wins/W'.

The correct standings should be:

Edmonton (NW) 80
Anaheim (PAC) 74
Columbus (CEN) 71
Dallas (PAC) 73
Chicago (CEN) 71
Winnipeg (CEN) 71

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use the same principle you use to pts for wins something like ` AND w = (select max(w) from .....)`

Comment: ...what happens if teams have the same number of points **and** wins?

Comment: show a sqlfiddle.com with schema and data.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse would have a 3rd statement, whoever has a greater differential (DIFF)

Comment: Here's a sqlfiddle @Drew http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f377e7/5/0

Comment: did you get it to work so as to not have to look at it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Query

```
select team,`div`,pts,1 as sortOrder 
from 
(   -- note use parentheses to avoid mysql error 1221
    (select team,`div`,pts,@cen:=team from `standings_west` where `div`='CEN' order by pts desc limit 1) 
    union all 
    (select team,`div`,pts,@pac:=team from `standings_west` where `div`='PAC' order by pts desc limit 1) 
    union all 
    (select team,`div`,pts,@nw:=team from `standings_west` where `div`='NW' order by pts desc limit 1) 
) xDerived1 
cross join (select @cen='',@pac='',@nw='') params 
union 
select team,`div`,pts,sortOrder 
from 
(   select team,`div`,pts,2 as sortOrder 
    from `standings_west` 
    where team!=@cen and team!=@pac and team!=@nw 
    order by pts desc 
    limit 3 
) xDerived2 
order by sortOrder,pts desc;
```

### Results

```
+----------+-----+-----+-----------+
| team     | div | pts | sortOrder |
+----------+-----+-----+-----------+
| EDMONTON | NW  |  80 |         1 |
| ANAHEIM  | PAC |  74 |         1 |
| WINNIPEG | CEN |  71 |         1 |
| DALLAS   | PAC |  73 |         2 |
| CHICAGO  | CEN |  71 |         2 |
| COLUMBUS | CEN |  71 |         2 |
+----------+-----+-----+-----------+
```

### Stored Proc

The following depicts a stored proc just to show it in case you are having problems and need it.

```
drop procedure if exists xdoit;
delimiter $$
create procedure xdoit()
begin
select team,`div`,pts,1 as sortOrder 
from 
(   -- note use parentheses to avoid mysql error 1221
    (select team,`div`,pts,@cen:=team from `standings_west` where `div`='CEN' order by pts desc limit 1) 
    union all 
    (select team,`div`,pts,@pac:=team from `standings_west` where `div`='PAC' order by pts desc limit 1) 
    union all 
    (select team,`div`,pts,@nw:=team from `standings_west` where `div`='NW' order by pts desc limit 1) 
) xDerived1 
cross join (select @cen='',@pac='',@nw='') params 
union 
select team,`div`,pts,sortOrder 
from 
(   select team,`div`,pts,2 as sortOrder 
    from `standings_west` 
    where team!=@cen and team!=@pac and team!=@nw 
    order by pts desc 
    limit 3 
) xDerived2 
order by sortOrder,pts desc;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

### call stored proc

```
call xdoit();
```

A few comments here.

First, your sqlfiddle had data from the west, but a query from the east. Based on table names, I suggest you have all your data in one table not two and have a column for east or west.

The query uses a cross join to merely establish variables for grabbing the division leaders so those division leaders are excluded for the sortOrder=2 teams.

Tweak as necessary for tie-breaks (ie: the teams with 71 points) regarding your implemention of DIFF in comments to @Clockwork

Ask if you have any questions.

---

The following is the multi_query php solution I came up with for you based on your posting of a comment in that chat room.

The only solution I could come up with was the following based on clearly the results were coming back in two result sets. Thus the `while` loop that is driven by `next_result()`. The first result set has the top 3 rows, the 2nd result set has the twelve rows that follow. That is just the way PHP seems to see it.

Also note that in the PHP part, since I seemed to be dealing with a multi_query, I took advantage of that and passed the mysql parameters in versus doing a `cross join` to pick them up.

### PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>RGMG: Standings</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
    //mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    error_reporting(E_ALL); // report all PHP errors
    ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

    try {
        $mysqli= new mysqli('localhost', 'dbUser', 'thePassword', 'theDbName'); 

        echo "<table><div><br><br>";    // note you had this line a little bit wrong


        // notice below the concat of the $sql and the multi_query()
        $sql = "set @cen:='',@pac:='',@nw:=''; ";
        $sql .= "select *
                from
                (   select team,`div`,gp,win,lose,otl,goalsF,goalsA,diff,gpg,gaa,pts,1 as sortOrder 
                    from 
                    (   -- note use parentheses to avoid mysql error 1221
                        (select team,`div`,gp,win,lose,otl,goalsF,goalsA,diff,gpg,gaa,pts,@cen:=team from `standings_west` where `div`='CEN' order by pts desc, win desc, diff desc limit 1) 
                        union all 
                        (select team,`div`,gp,win,lose,otl,goalsF,goalsA,diff,gpg,gaa,pts,@pac:=team from `standings_west` where `div`='PAC' order by pts desc, win desc, diff desc limit 1) 
                        union all 
                        (select team,`div`,gp,win,lose,otl,goalsF,goalsA,diff,gpg,gaa,pts,@nw:=team from `standings_west` where `div`='NW' order by pts desc, win desc, diff desc limit 1) 
                    ) xDerived1 
                    union all
                    select team,`div`,gp,win,lose,otl,goalsF,goalsA,diff,gpg,gaa,pts,sortOrder 
                    from 
                    (   select team,`div`,gp,win,lose,otl,goalsF,goalsA,diff,gpg,gaa,pts,2 as sortOrder 
                        from `standings_west` 
                        where team!=@cen and team!=@pac and team!=@nw 
                        order by pts desc 
                    ) xDerived2
                ) xDerived3 
                order by sortOrder,pts desc";

        echo "<div class='container'>";
        echo "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/sjDHhIV.png' width='100%' alt='West'>";
        echo "<table class='table table-condensed'>
        <tr class='top'>
        <th class='rank'></th>
        <th class='team'>TEAM</th>
        <th>DIV</th>
        <th>GP</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>L</th>
        <th class='otl'>OTL</th>
        <th class='pts'>PTS</th>
        <th>GF</th>
        <th>GA</th>
        <th>DIFF</th>
        <th>GPG</th>
        <th>GAA</th>
        ";
        $counter=1;
        $mysqli->multi_query($sql);
        while(true) {
            if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $gpg = ($row['goalsF']);
                    $gaa = ($row['goalsA']);

                    if ($row['gp'] != 0 ){
                        $gpg = ($row['goalsF'] / $row['gp']);
                        $gaa = ($row['goalsA'] / $row['gp']);
                    }
                    else {
                        $row['gp'] = "";
                    }

                    echo "<tr>
                        <td class='rank'>" . "$counter" . "</td>
                        <td class='team'>" . $row['team'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['div'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['gp'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['win'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['lose'] . "</td>
                        <td class='otl'>" . $row['otl'] . "</td>
                        <td class='pts'>" . $row['pts'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['goalsF'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['goalsA'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['diff'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . round($gpg, 2) . "</td>
                        <td>" . round($gaa, 2) . "</td>";
                    $counter++;
                }
                $result->free();
            }
            if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
                $mysqli->next_result();
            }                   
            else {
                break;
            }   
        }
        echo "</table></div>";

        $mysqli->close();
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Drew! I modified it a bit as you mentioned, and its working in the fiddle. But for some reason, on my website, its only showing the first 3 rows, the Union doesn't seem to be working.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f377e7/31 ||  http://rgmgstandings.tk/

Comment: alright I'll think about it some more. btw it is of interest cuz NHL is all my brother lives and breathes and I want the same for him. He is a sports stats kinda extreme type. Keep me posted (I guess mainly in my [mysql chat room on the stack](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/mysql-stuff))

Answer (score 1):

First i love NHL and from your query we can say the table you are showing us is standings_east,so let's try this:

```
    select team,DIV,GP,W,L,OTL,PTS,GF,GA,DIFF,GPG,GAA,1 as sort_key 
      from standings_east t
      where exists 
       (select 1 
          from 
           (select DIV,max(PTS) as PTS,max(W) as W from standings_east 
              group by DIV) a 
          where t.DIV=a.DIV and t.PTS=a.PTS and t.W=a.W
       )
   UNION ALL
   select team,DIV,GP,W,L,OTL,PTS,GF,GA,DIFF,GPG,GAA,2 as sort_key 
     from standings_east t
     where not exists 
       (select 1 
          from 
           (select DIV,max(PTS) as PTS,max(W) as W from standings_east 
              group by DIV) a 
        where t.DIV=a.DIV and t.PTS=a.PTS and t.W=a.W
       )
  order by sort_key,PTS DESC
```

i think there is some better way but this is the one like yours the most and the easiest to understand just add a group by on your code and Merry Christmas

Comment: Hey thanks my man, I probably should of provided a sqlfiddle to begin with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f377e7/5/0 Merry Christmas to you!

Comment: Oh,i already did that but i don't know how to edit sqlfiddle into here. u can check mine  i think it's what you want :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6003/4